# NoClassDefFoundError: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in Spring/REST Tutorial

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to build and run this tutorial "Designing and Implementing RESTful Web Services with Spring" off-line, using a local repository for my dependencies. Here is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
flatDir { dirs 'lib' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5'
    // {!begin jackson}
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'
    // {!end jackson}
    // {!begin jaxb}
    runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.9'
    // {!end jaxb}
    // {!begin commons}
    runtime 'org.apache.commons:commons-logging:1.1.1'
    // {!end commons}

    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"

    testCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}
```

Some of the tests fail with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

This class is in the spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, which is in the dependencies. What am I missing?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class was on the classpath at compile time but is missing at runtime.  Check your _runtime_ classpath.

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace please. I am not sure but i think there is a class missing, that is required by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: That error means that the JVM has already tried and failed to load the mentioned class.  If you rerun your tests, what is the first exception message you see that mentions that class?